# Best way to overwrite Divi (Wordpress theme) CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm wondering what the best was is to overwrite the Divi Wordpress theme CSS styles. I have A LOT of CSS to overwrite. Ideally I'd create a custom theme but it's been specified to me that it has to be done with Divi. Primarily so widgets can be added by staff as the site grows.

It's probably worth noting I am using a child theme of the Divi theme.

I thought this would be easy enough using "Appearance" > "Editor", then just type my own CSS. But anything I type, for example:

```
body {
    font-family: "Acumin Pro Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}
```

Is overwritten by the styles specified in "Themes" > "Customise". There is a "Additional CSS" option in here but it's a 300px wide box which is going to me a pain to use for the volume of CSS I need to write, not to mentioned maintain. But I don't want to add `!important` to overwrite everything in "Appearance" > "Editor" either.

What are peoples thoughts/ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

In the admin area of your site, on the left hand side go to:

Divi > Theme Options

Scroll all the way down past all the options and you will see a "Custom CSS" section. You can add your css here and it will overwrite the defaults. It will also be preserved here throughout all future theme updates.

Comment: And this text box can be expanded by dragging the handle at the bottom right. This makes it much easier to view and edit your css.

Answer (score 0):

Never use css in the customizer and always make a child theme to group your own css.

If any value is save within the theme customizer, delete it in the database...

Comment: I am using a child theme. But the Divi 'child' theme also has it's own master/global styles. I guess the CSS in "Editor" is maybe loaded after these? Maybe re-ordering them would help?

Comment: @user1406440 if you have enqueued your child theme style sheet properly (as per [link](https://digwp.com/2016/01/include-styles-child-theme/)) it should be loaded last. The exception to this is the annoying style-cpt.css stylesheet for custom post types that is loaded after enqueued stylesheets.